# How can I configure Pyramid's JSON encoding?

Tags: python, json, pyramid, pymongo

I'm trying to return a function like this:

```
@view_config(route_name='CreateNewAccount', request_method='GET', renderer='json')
def returnJSON(color, message=None):
    return  json.dumps({ "color" : "color", "message" : "message" }, default=json_util.default)
```

Because of Pyramid's own JSON encoding, it's coming out double-encoded like this:

```
"{\"color\": \"color\", \"message\": \"message\"}"
```

How can I fix this?  I need to use the [`default` argument](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/json_util.html) (or equivalent) because it's required for Mongo's custom types.

Comment: This is not a strange formatting. This is a *normal* stringified JSON format, it uses escaped quotes.

Comment: @VisioN: It *is* normal JSON formatting... *for a string*.

Comment: Why am I don't I get the error if I pass in straight JSON (without JSON.dumps)?

Comment: You're not passing the `color` and `message` parameters into your json dict by the way.

Comment: Anyone know how I can unescape/unstringify this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like the dictionary is being JSON-encoded twice, the equivalent of:

```
json.dumps(json.dumps({ "color" : "color", "message" : "message" }))
```

Perhaps your Python framework automatically JSON-encodes the result? Try this instead:

```
def returnJSON(color, message=None):
  return { "color" : "color", "message" : "message" }
```

**EDIT:**

To use a custom Pyramid renderer that generates JSON the way you want, try this (based on the [renderer docs](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/renderers.html) and the [renderer sources](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/renderers.py)).

In startup:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.renderers import JSON

config = Configurator()
config.add_renderer('json_with_custom_default', JSON(default=json_util.default))
```

Then you have a 'json_with_custom_default' renderer to use:

```
@view_config(route_name='CreateNewAccount', request_method='GET', renderer='json_with_custom_default')
```

**EDIT 2**

Another option could be to return a `Response` object which he renderer shouldn't modify. E.g.

```
from pyramid.response import Response
def returnJSON(color, message):
  json_string = json.dumps({"color": color, "message": message}, default=json_util.default)
  return Response(json_string)
```

Comment: That works, like I mentioned in the post. I need to use JSON.dumps though because I need default=json_util.default to serialize Mongo objects.

Comment: Which Python web framework are you using? You need to disable the automatic JSON encoding, or find a way to modify the way the framework does the JSON encoding.

Comment: I'm using Pyramid. It is set with a renderer: @view_config(route_name='CreateNewAccount', request_method='GET', renderer='json')

Comment: Added sample code and links for Pyramid custom renderers, perhaps this will help you

Comment: Wow orip...this is seriously impressive. Are you using Pyramid as well? Also, you were the first to correctly guess the root of my problem (double encoding) Very impressive

Comment: Thanks, and no, I don't use Pyramid, but all web frameworks in all languages have the same issues :)

Comment: I'm getting a "Global named JSON is not defined" error from the config.add_renderer line

Comment: does default=json_util.default need to be wrapped in JSON()?

Comment: I think the problem is this feature is for Pyramid 1.4 and I'm on 1.3 source: http://readthedocs.org/docs/pyramid/en/master/api/renderers.html

Comment: (1) Could be that you need `from pyramid.renderers import JSON`. (2) the `JSON` class forwards the keyword arguments given in its constructor to the `json.dumps` function (see the source I linked), so creating an instance of `JSON` with `default=json_util.default` should use the correct options. (3) If that doesn't work, try encoding in JSON yourself like you started with, but wrapping it in a `Response` to prevent any renderers from modifying it. You may have to set the content-type and other HTTP headers yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other excellent answers, I'd like to point out that if you don't want the data returned by your view function to be passed through json.dumps then you should not use renderer="json" in the view configuration :)

So instead of

```
@view_config(route_name='CreateNewAccount', request_method='GET', renderer='json')
def returnJSON(color, message=None):
    return  json.dumps({ "color" : "color", "message" : "message" }, default=json_util.default)
```

you can just use

```
@view_config(route_name='CreateNewAccount', request_method='GET', renderer='string')
def returnJSON(color, message=None):
    return  json.dumps({ "color" : "color", "message" : "message" }, default=json_util.default)
```

`string` renderer will just pass the string data returned by your function as-is. However, registering a custom renderer is a nicer approach (see @orip's answer)

Comment: This is true and it's the solution I'm using now. I'll have to wait until Pyramid 1.4 is released to use a custom renderer.

Comment: I think you've misread the documentation - registering custom renderers has been available in Pyramid for a long time, I'm using a custom renderer in an appication since the times Pyramid was called repoze.bfg. http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/renderers.html#adding-a-new-renderer

Comment: I should have been more specific...I mean the JSON() function for creating renderer params has only been added in 1.4

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say, but I will assume you are just using the standard `json` module.

The `json` module doesn't define a class for JSON; it uses a standard Python `dict` as the "native" representation of your data.  `json.dumps()` encodes a `dict` as a JSON string; `json.loads()` takes a JSON string and gives back a `dict`.

So instead of doing this:

```
def returnJSON(color, message=None):
    return  json.dumps({ "color" : "color", "message" : "message" }, default=json_util.default)
```

Try doing this:

```
def returnJSON(color, message=None):
    return { "color" : "color", "message" : "message" }
```

Just pass back a plain `dict`.  See how your iPhone app likes this.

Answer (score 0):

You are [dumping the *string*](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps) of the Python object (dictionary) you are giving it.

The manual for json.dumps states:

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str.

To convert back from the string, you will need to use the [Python JSON function loads](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads) which LOADS a string into a JSON object.

What it appears you are trying to do however, is `encode` a python dictionary to JSON.

```
def returnJSON(color, message=None):
    return  json.encode({ "color" : color, "message" : message })
```

Comment: The problem is not the initial dumps.  The problem is that it's being encoded *again* down the line.

Comment: I agree. Its probably caused by this line: @view_config(route_name='CreateNewAccount', request_method='GET', renderer='json')

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen is correct...now I need to figure out how I can disable that

Comment: @yourfriendzak, this is now really a Pyramid and pymongo question, so you should edit it accordingly.  I've given you a start.